# Difference between TVar and TMVar

Tags: haskell, concurrency, stm

I've seen the `TVar` is a simple container, while the `TMVar` is the same as an `MVar`, meaning it has a lock etc, but within the `STM` monad. I am wondering why would that be necessary, as the idea of the `STM` is to make locks unnecessary.

So which is the one to use if you, say have a type like `[Handle]` a list of socket handles that you want to use between threads made by `forkIO`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's not really a matter of locking, it's about what the reference means:

- `TVar` is a mutable reference within `STM`, representing general shared state. You create it holding a value, you can read and write to it, etc. It's very much akin to `IORef` or `STRef` (which are the same thing anyway).
- `TMVar` is a reference to a slot that threads can use to communicate. It can be created holding a value, or empty. You can put a value into it, which if already filled blocks until someone else empties it; or you can take a value from it, which if already empty blocks until someone fills it. It's obviously akin to an `MVar`, but for many common uses it might be simpler to think of it as a single-element queue used for a communicating producer/consumer pair.

In short, `TVar` is general shared state, use it if you want atomic updates to data from arbitrary places. `TMVar` is a synchronization primitive, use it if you want a thread to wait until something becomes available, while another waits for something to be needed.

Also note `TChan`, which is implemented roughly as two `TVar`s holding locations in a linked list where each forward link is also a `TVar`, and works as an unbounded queue for communication.

All of these can be used in slightly different ways, of course--you can peek at the value of a `TMVar` without removing it, for instance, if you want a scenario where multiple threads all wait for a single resource to become available but it's never "used up".

Answer (score 19):

The differences between `TVar` and `TMVar` are not so large as they look -- definitely not comparable to the differences between `IORef` and `MVar`.

While `MVar` does indeed provide some locking for thread-safety, `TMVar` does nothing interesting! (no additional locking) Everything important is already implemented with `STM` and `TVar`, so `TMVar a` is just a short-hand for `TVar (Maybe a)` equipped with some nice functions (some of which block using the `retry` function).

Whether blocking with `retry` is compatible with the spirit of `STM` and whether it eliminates some of the STM's advantages (no deadlocks etc.) is a separate question and I would love to see someone more experienced to answer it.

Comment: How would `retry` cause deadlocks? It rolls back the current transaction, then blocks until the situation changes somehow. It doesn't (in fact, can't) block inside a transaction.

Comment: Although it won't deadlock in the middle of a transaction, one can create transactions that can never succeed in a way similar to how classical deadlocks are created, like two transactions waiting for each other's results. It's not immediately obvious how this is different from deadlock in practice.

Comment: Ah, right. I believe the actual term for that is, appropriately enough, "livelock". It's more a kind of resource starvation than it is like a deadlock, though. Whereas deadlocks can easily result from unrelated uses of the same resources, I believe the optimistic nature of STM makes livelocks unlikely unless there's a direct conflict or very high overall contention.